# make oldconfig overwriting value in .config

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile

I'm attempting to compile the linux kernel and use a custom .config file.

So I copy the .config to my folder where the kernel source is, and run "make oldconfig" on the file to see if I'm missing anything. However, it appears that doing so modifies a few of my values back to what they were before I edited them:

```
< CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS=y
---
> CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS=n
< # CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA is not set
< # CONFIG_DEBUG_SET_MODULE_RONX is not set
---
> CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA=n
> CONFIG_DEBUG_SET_MODULE_RONX=n
```

How can I get oldconfig to keep the values as they were modified?

Thanks

Comment: do `make menuconfig`, copy the `.config` and then do `make menuconfig` again

Comment: When I copy the file, run oldconfig, modify the values back and run oldconfig again it does what I wrote above. Only the three values get changed. I've also tried running make mrproper as well, to no avail.

Comment: Did you set `CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS=n` manually in `.config`?

Comment: Yep. It changes it back to CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS=y when I run oldconfig. I shouldn't need to do it through menuconfig, should I? I thought that was the point of oldconfig, is that it bases the changes off the old .config

Comment: Try making it `# CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS is not set`.. I had never seen anything like `CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS=n`

Comment: RODATA and SET_MODULE_RONX prompt me now, which isn't really any better than explicitly forcing 'n', but CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS=y still.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72598/discussion-between-miline-and-jordan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually kernel config options are dependent on other config options. So even if you disable one config option, as its enabled by some other config option it will fall back to its original value after you do `make oldconfig`

In case of `CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS` it depends on or set by several other flags `TRACING [=y] || BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE [=y] && TRACING_SUPPORT [=y] && FTRACE [=y] && SYSFS [=y] && BLOCK [=y]`

Try setting one by one of them to `=n` along with `CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS=n` and see if its persistent after doing `make oldconfig`. For me setting `CONFIG_FTRACE=n` worked

How to find dependency. Run `make menuconfig`. Press `/` to search the config option and see the `Selected by`. Those are the config flags who are also setting your config option. See their current value next to them. For e.g. above you can see that `TRACING_SUPPORT` is set to `y`

Comment: Yep, looks like it was CONFIG_FTRACE that was the dependency for me. Thanks